# Why isn't terraform interpolation working?

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure, azure-rm-template

So my goal is to have write a terraform code to deploy 3 resource groups in AZ dev, uat and prod with each having the following resources.

SQL Database
Key Vault

variable.tf

```
variable "resource_group_name" {
    description = "deafault resource group"
    type = list (string)
    default = ["Test-dev","Test-uat","Test-prod"]
}


variable "storage_account_name" {
  description = "name for storage account"
  default     = "test-storageact"
}
```

main.tf

```
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "resgrp" {
  for_each = toset(var.resource_group_name)
  name     = "${var.resource_group_name}-rg-${each.value}"
  location = var.location
  tags = {
    "Environment" = "${var.env}-${each.value}"
  }
}
resource "azurerm_storage_account" "storageact" {
  for_each                 = toset(var.resource_group_name)
  name                     = "${var.storage_account_name}-${each.value}"
  resource_group_name      = azurerm_resource_group.resgrp["${each.value}"].location
  location                 = azurerm_resource_group.resgrp["${each.value}"].name
  account_tier             = "Standard"
  account_replication_type = "LRS"

  tags = {
    "Environment" = "${var.env}-${each.value}"
  }
}
```

error message

```
│ Error: Invalid template interpolation value
│
│   on main.tf line 3, in resource "azurerm_resource_group" "resgrp":
│    3:   name     = "${var.resource_group_name}-rg-${each.value}"
│     ├────────────────
│     │ var.resource_group_name is list of string with 3 elements
│
│   on main.tf line 6, in resource "azurerm_resource_group" "resgrp":
│    6:     "Environment" = "${var.env}-${each.value}"
│     ├────────────────
│     │ var.env is map of string with 3 elements
│
│ Cannot include the given value in a string template: string required.
╵
Operation failed: failed running terraform plan (exit 1)
```

please any help will be greatly appreciated.

i tried using type = map(string) in the variable but still gave me an error.

Comment: The error messages are telling you whats wrong. `var.resource_group_name` is a list of strings. You can't print a list of string, only a single string. Same with `var.env`. What are you expecting these strings to contain?

Comment: I was able to update it to 

resource "azurerm_resource_group" "resgrp" {
  for_each = toset(var.resource_group_name)
  name     = each.value
  location = var.location
  tags = {
    "Environment" = "${each.value}"
  }
}

 and no errors. 

it could deploy all 3 resource groups. 
Please how can i correctly specify the creation of the rest of the resources
within each resource group is where i am having issues.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few problems with the code.

`var.resource_group_name` is a list containing 3 string elements (by default), and thus the error: `var.resource_group_name is list of string with 3 elements` explains the problem, and is illustrated below.

The `var.env` is a map consisting of 3 elements and also being used as a string and fails for the same reason.

```
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "resgrp" {
  for_each = toset(var.resource_group_name)
  # var.resource_group_name is actually a list, but it's being
  #  used as a string here, which will fail.
  name     = "${var.resource_group_name}-rg-${each.value}"
  location = var.location
  tags = {
    "Environment" = "${var.env}-${each.value}"
  }
}
```

You probably instead want:

```
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "resgrp" {
  for_each = toset(var.resource_group_name)
  name     = "${each.value}-rg"
  location = var.location
  tags = {
    "Environment" = "${each.value}"
  }
}
```

---

Additionally, as an alternative to the approach of putting multiple environments in a single resource construct, consider [using modules to create reusable infrastructure](https://blog.gruntwork.io/how-to-create-reusable-infrastructure-with-terraform-modules-25526d65f73d) for your resources and then calling each module for the environment that you're using, this is a best practice when implementing duplicate or near-duplicate infrastructure across multiple environments and allows you some flexibility with naming conventions and other parameters that would differ based upon the environment.

Rough example:

```
module "test-dev" {
  source = "../modules/infrastructure"

  environment = "Test-dev"
  vm_count = 1
}

module "test-uat" {
  source = "../modules/infrastructure"

  environment = "Test-dev"
  vm_count = 3
}

module "test-prod" {
  source = "../modules/infrastructure"

  environment = "Test-prod"
  account_tier = "Premium"
  vm_count = 6
}
```